# ASP.NET Core with react.js, react-leaflet - TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, react-leaflet

As described in the title above, I'm using ASP.NET Core 7 with react.js and would like to use react-leaflet there, but am obviously overwhelmed to even display the map.

I have looked at 2 things

- https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/start-setup/
  and
- https://codesandbox.io/s/mapping-state-in-react-leaflet-forked-k8fjxl?file=/src/index.js:176-183

and unfortunately not managed to get the map displayed in the console I get the following errors:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
>
> react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <ForwardRef(Ne)>
> component:
>
> Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
> Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
>
> react-dom.development.js:26923 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')

I would have tried the whole thing as follows

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    MapContainer,
    TileLayer,
    useMap, Popup, Marker
} from 'https://cdn.esm.sh/react-leaflet'

export class Home extends Component {
  static displayName = Home.name;

  render() {
    return (
        <MapContainer center={[51.505, -0.09]} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
            <TileLayer
                attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />
            <Marker position={[51.505, -0.09]}>
                <Popup>
                    A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
                </Popup>
            </Marker>
        </MapContainer>    );
  }
}
```

Hope to get some tips here

Comment: The [example I downloaded from the repository](https://github.com/stadiamaps/react-leaflet-demo/) at [this link](https://docs.stadiamaps.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-react-leaflet/) works, but I get the same error as you when building the example myself. I don't know what I'm missing, you can check [this link](https://docs.stadiamaps.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-react-leaflet/) and [its repository](https://github.com/stadiamaps/react-leaflet-demo/).